# Кодировка в csv файл

Tags: python

Подскажите, какую кодировку в коде нужно указать что бы не было крякозяблов ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  with codecs.open(f'{city}_{cur_time}.csv', 'w+', encoding='utf-8', ) as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)

        writer.writerow(
            (
                'Продукт',
                'Старая цена',
                'Новая цена',
                'Процент скидки',
                'Время акции',
            )
        )

    for item in cards:
        try:
            card_title = item.find('div', class_='card-sale__title').text.strip()
            card_discount = item.find('div', class_='card-sale__discount').text.strip()
            card_price_old_integer = item.find('div', class_='label__price_old').find('span', class_='label__price-integer').text.strip()
            card_price_old_decimal = item.find('div', class_='label__price_old').find('span', class_='label__price-decimal').text.strip()
            card_old_price = f'{card_price_old_integer}.{card_price_old_decimal}'
            card_price_integer = item.find('div', class_='label__price_new').find('span', class_='label__price-integer').text.strip()
            card_price_decimal = item.find('div', class_='label__price_new').find('span', class_='label__price-decimal').text.strip()
            card_price_new = f'{card_price_integer}.{card_price_decimal}'
            card_sale_data = item.find('div', class_='card-sale__date').text.strip().replace('\n', ' ')

            with codecs.open(f'{city}_{cur_time}.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)

                writer.writerow(
                    (
                        card_title,
                        card_old_price,
                        card_price_new,
                        card_discount,
                        card_sale_data
                    )

                )

        except AttributeError:
            continue

    print(f'Файл {city}_{cur_time}.cvs успешно записан !')
```

Comment: Используйте кодировку `utf-8-sig` при создании файла. Это соответствует кодировке `UTF-8 With BOM` в Windows. А вообще добрый Вам совет не используйте Excel для работы с CSV. LibreOffice Вам в помощ

Answer (score 1):

Если это `Windows` и `Excel`, то скорее всего подойдёт `encoding='cp1251'`, ещё можно попробовать `encoding='utf-8-sig'`, спасибо @Namerek за напоминание.
Кроме того, у экселя другой разделитель, попробуйте `csv.writer(file, delimiter=";")`.

Comment: не помогло. Пробовал такую кодировку. Ошибка следующая.  'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2212' in position 59: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Да, бывают и такие символы юникода, которые не получается преобразовать в `cp1251`.

Comment: нужно решение. Буду благодарен.

Comment: А вам главное чтобы в целом загрузилось или чтобы все символы всё же сохранились? Хотя всё-равно нужно будет разбираться-вспоминать. Поиском не пользовались, тут вообще эта тема не раз вроде разбиралась?

Comment: @CrazyElf, сам убил кучу времени пока нашел. `utf-8-sig` решает проблему

Comment: @Namerek А, точно, видел же на английской версии SO такой вариант

Comment: @CrazyElf, там кстати и нашел помоему, где-то в коментах к ооочень не популярному вопросу )))) Причем искаал совсем другое.

Comment: У Excel разделитель параметров в функциях ';' а разделитель полей csv как раз запятая

Answer (score 0):

Поробуйте использовать `utf-8`:

**[UTF-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)** поддерживает и кириллицу, и буквы английского алфавита.